# Docker swarm service port isn't accessible

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I'm quite a noob to docker and I read the official tutorial how to use it in the previous days.
I decided to deploy my very simple spring-boot application as a service into a swarm, but I cannot reach it from outside. By the way when I start the docker with docker run, the container is accessible.

So my spring-boot tomcat is listening on 8081.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-alpine

VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8081

ADD docker-demo-1.0.jar app.jar

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-
jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: neyma6/demo:3.0
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - webnet
  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

I deployed 2 services, a visualiser and a spring-boot app. The visualiser is accessible on http://localhost:8082/ but the app isn't on http://localhost:8081/test

```
docker swarm init
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml demo
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: somebody found the answer, because I have the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053147/docker-swarm-with-springboot-app

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you deployed this docker stack on your local(1 node), but you tried to open 2 containers(replicas) on the same 8081 port. Port will be conflict.

Change replicas to 1 and then try again.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, I guess there shouldn't be any problem with the instances, because they are behind docker's load balancer.

Comment: I think you need to get more information by using "docker service ps demo_web", "docker ps", "docker logs", and "docker inspect". You may also attach to the container like "docker exec -it XXX bash". And then you can check your application in the container.

Comment: Thanks man, docker logs helped me find out that there wasn't enough memory provided... The interesting part is that the visualizer showed the containers as running containers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the issue, there wasn't enough memory provided to the spring-boot running container...